# How does other applications handle large text files without having a large memory foot print?

Tags: java, parsing, java-7, large-files

I need to know how applications like Bairtail or Baregrep can handle such large text files without having a huge foot print?

I am trying to do something similar in Java as in question:

[Viewing large log files in JavaFX in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239138/viewing-large-log-files-in-javafx-in-a-listview)

But when I handle large text log files (900Mb up to 2.5Gb of text) I am running into issues. The JVM memory size increase dramatically when I read the text files.

One other way was to only retrieve the lines that I am interested in. but I am not aware of any technology to do this in java. I have to start reading line by line until I get to the required line that I want (let’s say line 1000) and then grab hold of that text. But in doing so I have 999 lines in memory which is waiting to be GC’d.

Bairgrep for instance is scanning multiple files in a folder and look for a pattern. If I open the task manager I can hardly see that the memory footprint is growing. What type of technology or way of scanning is these programs using.

Is there a technology out there that I can use in my application to handle large text files?

---

I might add that my log file is files that is generated by a java application and the length of each line is not the same.

One correction... with memory footprint I mean I cannot read a 6Gb file in memory. Event if I specify the VM size with -Xmx to be small. The application is running out of memory when reading the 6Gb file.

---

Added 2 ways I tried to get the text from the 758 Mb Log file

Method 1

```
 @FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    final String fileName = "D:/Development/Logs/File1.log";
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        while (in.ready()) {
            String s = in.readLine();
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Method 2

```
 @FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    final String fileName = "D:/Development/Logs/File1.log";        
    Scanner scan = null;
    try {            
        File file = new File(fileName);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            return;
        }
        scan = new Scanner(file);
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            final String line = scan.nextLine();                     
        }            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    } finally {
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Data which is "waiting to be GC'd" does not increase your application's memory footprint. If you want less footprint, then specifify it with `-Xmx`.

Comment: @Marko-I updated the question. What I mean is if I make the VM too small it runs out of memory when reading the file.

Comment: If you're running out of memory,  then there's an issue with your code. If you don't retain earlier lines in memory, there is no reason for an OOME.

Comment: Let's see some code.  There's no reason java has to hold onto every line it reads from a file.

Comment: Added code using BufferedReader and scanner class. Both cases each time the method is called the memory jumps about 200mb.

Answer (score 1):

I think "MemoryMappedFile" is what you are looking for.

I found some links to help you:
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm
http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/01/memorymapped-file-and-io-in-java.html

Comment: The thing is my log files have 1000's of lines of variable length which makes it difficult to read lines let’s say at line nos 998-1024
So many sites states that this should not be used 

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2072711

Answer (score 0):

Both the applications you mentioned, might "handle" large files, but they **don't actually need to load entire files into memory**. The first one sounds like it might seek directly to the end of the file, while the second operates on a line by line basis.

It is possible they are using native code via JNI to achieve the low memory use.

Edit: Infact, they look to be purely C or C++ applications, they **don't need to wait for GC like Java applications** do.

Comment: The difference is definitely not about automatic memory management (aka. GC).

Comment: Is there a 3rd party library that can be used by java to do this?
I need to be able to scan each line to see if it contains a string and the ability to read a specific number of lines - lets say line number 998 to line number 1024.